# Android TabActivity Back key Event

Tags: android

I tried to go back when pressing back button in tabActivity. previously i did

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
            showDialog(DIALOG_REALLY_EXIT_ID);

        return true;

    }
private void showlist() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

But this event never called in TabActivity. i dont know how to get back from tabActivity, I am new to android, can anyone give me pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override onBackPressed() in tab activity ,

For more details or problem you might encounter , check this post,

[Key Events in TabActivities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796050/key-events-in-tabactivities)

Comment: I also used onBackPressed() function