# Back Button not working in the TabActivity

Tags: android, back-button, tabactivity

I have implemented 3 Tabs in my applications using TabHost and TabActivity. Each Tab has its own ActivityGroup.I am using Android 2.2

I have overridden onBackPressed() and onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  in all of my child activities in each tab. But it works only in the first child activity. In the remaining child activities the application stops working after i click on Back button

This is the first time i have implemented Tab activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the solution on the following link

[Android TabActivity Back key Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662541/android-tabactivity-back-key-event)

You need to override onBackPressed() method in your class which implements ActivityGroup and keep a stack of activities so that you can popup them when we click back button.

Answer (score 2):

You can add another tab to go back:

```
tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_HOME);
tabSpec.setIndicator(TAB_HOME);
tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, Home.class));
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```