# Android, How to receive home button click through broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-homebutton

In my application I need to send log-out request to server when ever user goes out of application via clicking on log-out button or closing application by pressing home button key.

There is no problem with button and result is as I expect. The problem is how to get home button. Based on my research it is not possible to use `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` as we can use for getting back button.

The solution that I'm thinking about is registering a receiver and sending a broadcast whenever Home button clicked. So through receiver I can launch a service to send log-out request to server.

My current problem is I cannot get home button whenever i click it. This the code that I have written:

**manifest.xml**

```
<application ...

        <receiver android:name="HomeButtonReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

</application>
```

**HomeButtonReceiver**

```
public class HomeButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private final String TAG = "HomeButtonReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "inside onReceive()...");
    }
}
```

Any comments/suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: With [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025660/override-home-and-back-button-is-case-a-boolean-is-true/10025904#10025904) you can handle Home button, so just send broadcast on it.

Comment: Thanks hotveryspicy, I tested your way but I was not successful. It could capture volume up/down but i couldn't get home press.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use `dispatchKeyEvent` function. It can intercept the HOME button pressing event.

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent keyevent) {

        if (keyevent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
            //Do here what you want
            return true;
        }
        else
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks SahilMahajanMj, i modified your code to if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
         Log.i(TAG, "inside dispatchKeyEvent()...");
            return true;
        }
        else
         Log.i(TAG, "...");
             
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event); This code could capture volume up/down but when i presses home button nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is like this

Create your Home button event catcher

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME){
       //Send your own custom broadcast message
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Now you can create a broadcast receiver so that you can receive your message

You can refer [here](http://mobisys.in/blog/2012/01/android-sending-receiving-broadcast-messages/) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/kXNk5PQ2ri8) for how to send a broadcast messsage

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to find out when ever the user goes out of application , why don't you use the `onPause(..)` method of the `Activity`?

Comment: Thanks Binoy Babu, It is because when user closes the app then I need to send a request to server to cancel session id. If I do your suggested way then user cannot browse application. Therefore, I need to know when user closes application then I send that request.