# how to show a AlertDialog while Pressing the HomeButton

Tags: android

Hi I have written the following code:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode,KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        showDialog(MY_DALOG);
        return  true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But when I press the `HOME BUTTON`, it doesn't call the line `if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)` when debugging.

On the other hand, it calls the `onPause()`. I have put my code in `onPause()` but still, it shows a `SuperNotFound` exception in Logcat.

Any idea how to display a `dialog` by pressing the `HOMEKEY`?

Comment: You cannot "detect home key Button press event", sorry.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288850/keycode-home-doesnt-get-called-android/16288894#16288894

Comment: @HoanNguyen that is not the answer of my question i have seen application in they are showing alertdialog when pressing homebutton

Comment: In the answer I said you can infer, and that is what they do or make a home launcher.

Comment: A hack is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374673/android-see-if-home-key-is-pressed

Comment: it is working but the thing is dialog is showing and immediately disappears.

Answer (score 3):

The `Home Button` will be handled by the `PhoneWindowManager` in the `Android framework`. It will be sent to the `Launcher` application.
No other application will receive it in their Activity.

Answer (score 2):

KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME is not for the developers. Android has made it safe for themselves. So that no application would force the user to stay inside their application.

Comment: but i have seen some application where they are displaying alertdialogs by pressing home button

Comment: @user2295109 Can u please mention on which application you have seen that behaviour?

Comment: i dont think its necessary.

Comment: @user2295109 Well I don't know in which application you have seen that. But ideally it shouldn't happen as its not allowed in Android. For more info please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079691/overriding-the-home-button-how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-choice

Comment: @chandra Sekhar there should be some hack around i ave also seen many application they have this functionality.

Comment: @rickky Yes you are right. But do you think its really feasible for a developer to implement this?

Comment: It is not something that is allowed, so a hack is necessary. That's an extremely bad idea though imho. It is forbidden for a reason, if an user wants to go back to home, there is no legitimate reason to force him to stay in your app.

Comment: may be the developers intention is if the user accidentally pressed then home button it will show a warning for that may be for this he needs a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. you can show alert dialogue by pressing `back button` of device.

But, you can't implement those feature with `HOME Button` pressed. Because, Android is designed as automatically launch `home page` without consider about anything happening right now on UI, While pressing it.

Comment: that i know but i have seen many application have these features.

Comment: It's only achievable in Launcher applications.

Comment: if so, they might create their own home screen application. But, it is so difficult one.

Comment: @Dhasneem there should be some hack around i ave also seen many application they have this functionality

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible. But you have to make your own 'home screen replacement' app, and let the user set your app as the user's new home screen.
But this is probably a much more complicated solution than what you are looking for...