# Listen to Applications' Button on android system

Tags: android, actionlistener

am trying to catch the event of the press of the Android Applications' button , i searched in intent actions but i found nothing, i want to invoke some background service when user open thr applications' menu ,

[image: Applications Button on android system]

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android, How to receive home button click through broadcast receiver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302167/android-how-to-receive-home-button-click-through-broadcast-receiver)

Comment: It's not home button.

Comment: @Divers is right , this is not the home button , it's the applications' list button

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible, because it's depending on launcher, and I'm almost sure that developers don't send broadcast message when user press this button.