# Detect Home key press three times

Tags: android

I want to detect home key press three times from home screen of `android` such as after this  want to perform event. Is there any way to detect home key press three times in `android`.

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025660/override-home-and-back-button-is-case-a-boolean-is-true/10025904#10025904

Comment: This approach is no more working for latest versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to this in the Android OS, `PhoneWindowManager`, this is where the HOME button is handled.

Specificly: http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindowManager.java#1761

To change that you have to change and build the AOSP. And flash this on you device. Therefore for app developers this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If homekey is pressed in the activity it will come to

```
@Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
    }
```

put the counter and when it reached to 3 perform the action.

Comment: in the Class which extends activity and where you wanted to capture home button

Comment: i want to capture home key from home screen of android phone

Comment: so where is your application is running? is it a widget? or service?

Comment: then it's not possible because it's in the background UI less thing which is not affected with home key press.

Comment: is there any way rather than service

Comment: Depends on what are you doing with service?

Answer (score 0):

To `handle key event` you have to override the methods `onKeyDown()` and `onKeyUp().`

see [this](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/03/detect-key-action.html) link will guide you just you have to add your logic.

Comment: The HOME key will not be send to the Activity.

Comment: @PoweRoy I had not check it. i just know key concept.