# How can i make Change default appear each time my app starts in Android

Tags: android

All I want is to block home button when my app is running

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" >
            </category>
        </intent-filter>
```

I have written the above code in manifest when i start my app for the first time and i press home button it ask me to set my app or default mobile app to be set as default for home.. Once i select the default something other than my app and check the always checkbox.. The next time I start my app this dialog box never appears..

```
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        window.setType(LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD|LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN|LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN|LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        super.onAttachedToWindow();
    }
```

Do not work in Android 4.0 and above

Comment: You can't and should not do that. The home button always uses the system defined behaviour and is not for use as a means of navigation in your app.

Comment: Check this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025660/override-home-and-back-button-is-case-a-boolean-is-true/10025904#10025904

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override home button for Android4.0 onwards due to security reasons, to enable the user exit in case the application turns out to be a malware.

Plus, it is not a really good practice to not let the user navigate away from the application. But, if your application requires so, what you can do is declare the activity as a Launcher , so that when the HomeButton is pressed it will simply restart your application and remain there itself

Comment: How does the Toddler Lock work on Android 4.0... I am able to bring up the change default dialog once but second time when my app starts it do not work.. you may dialog that i am talking about in http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/how-to-change-a-default-application-in-ice-cream-sandwich

Comment: Home button cannot be overriden. You can write an application that responds to the home intent (that's what a launcher does) but that's all.

Comment: I am ok with it.. The only problemis it appear only once and then from next time it simply do not appear once something other than my app is set as default..