# Disabling home button on android 4.2

Tags: android

I would like to disable home button on android 4.2 to prevent user from closing the application. I read that I can't directly catch home button event on 4.2 so I may need to implement some home screen application??  I was wonder if there is any sample code to simply show this functionality ( Goal is not allowing the user to close the program.maybe rerun the program on key down).

Thanks in advance for the help,
Ray

Comment: Hi..Yes but didn't help on 4.2 Jelly bean

Comment: Thanks. I had seen that post before but I was wonder if there is any update or workaround to this problem.In that post one possible solution was implementing a home screen. So my question was is there any sample code to demonstrate how to implement home screen? It is also useful if I can rerun my application in case use clicks on hoe button.

Comment: Not sure about that, but you might find it easier to override some Key EventHandlers, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025660/override-home-and-back-button-is-case-a-boolean-is-true/10025904#10025904

Comment: Thanks Man..All these methods work on 2.x and not 4.x versions.So it seems for 4.x there is no straight forward work around to disable/catch home button event

Comment: You tried using KeyEvents? You should be able to use them in Android 4.0+.

Answer (score 3):

Make your app be the home screen. Then, pressing HOME will return the user to your app. There is a Home SDK sample in your SDK installation (if you chose to download SDK samples). Basically, you need an `<intent-filter>` on your activity like:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```