# Disable home button for staying in current screen for 4.0+

Tags: java, android, home-button

I have to create an app where the user can't go out of it.

The device is fixed in a car and should act as a login and info service. The user in the car should not go out of this app.

So I really have to find a solution to disable the home button.

Can you give me any solutions?

Comment: Its not possible to disable home button is android 4.0 for security reasons.

Comment: @Raghunandan home button can not be disable in any android :)

Comment: Apparently there is a way to simulate this, here is an accepted answer for ICS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12568747/2274885

Comment: @M.Bennett Do you know if its possible to restart the app and go back to the activity where you pressed the home button?

Comment: You could save a handful of flags in SharedPreferences when entering onPause...but i haven't implemented this before, so just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can not override home button.

[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5547818/1758960)

Read the comment of Commansware :)

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to disable home button in android 4.0 for security reasons.

If you want to control home button implement a home screen.

Check the below links

[Disable Home Button in Android ICS (4.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077675/disable-home-button-in-android-ics-4-0)

[Disabling home button on android 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396697/disabling-home-button-on-android-4-2)