# onBackPressed() is not working in ActivityGroup in android 4.0.3

Tags: android, tabactivity, android-tabactivity

I am working on TabActivity consist of 5 child activities. On pressing Back Button of TabActivity, it calls `onBackPressed()` method in android OS 2.3.4 but can't call the same method on android OS 4.0.3,

So I am not able to finish my TabActivity on Micromax Canvas Handset of 4.0.3 updated.

please let me know if any of you faced the same bug and its solution.

Answer (score 1):

I find solution to this on this link [Key Events in TabActivities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796050/key-events-in-tabactivities)

[Try first answer there. It is working for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6511638/1066828)

Good luck...