# back press not work to close tabactivity

Tags: android

i have tabactivity with 3 child activity, but i get issue back press not work to close Tab activity...

i set in Tab activity with

```
 @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
      }
```

and i set in each child activity with

```
@Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
        this.getParent().onBackPressed();   
      }
```

its seem not work, ho to fix it ? sorry for my english.. thanks

Comment: Do u want finish the activity ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Key Events in TabActivities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796050/key-events-in-tabactivities)

Comment: @Amsheer yes i want to finish tabactivity,

Comment: @VandanaSrivastava which the answer from that ? the first answer just i do, but not work :(

Comment: i just found, this code worked in my device but not work in other device like lenovo...

Comment: try to override onkey down and call finish() it'll work

Answer (score 0):

Try to add calling for finish() method inside your onBackPressed() method
ex:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  this.getParent().onBackPressed();  
  this.finish(); 
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
  this.finish(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i just found, this code worked in my device but not work in other device like lenovo...