# Android onBackPressed() not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to add this function:

-When clicking on Return button it pops an exit prompts `(AlertDialog with yes or no)`

**Problem**

But its not working properly. If I click on the button, it exits the program directly.

Here is my whole Activity Code :(**The exit function that I have tested is at the end of the code**)

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainScreen extends TabActivity {
    // TabSpec Names
    private static final String Alerts_SPEC = "Alertes";
    private static final String Status_SPEC = "Status";
    private static final String Details_SPEC = "Events";

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Inbox Tab
        TabSpec alertsSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(Alerts_SPEC);
        alertsSpec.setIndicator(Alerts_SPEC);
        Intent alertsIntent = new Intent(this, FragmentAlerts.class);
        alertsSpec.setContent(alertsIntent);

        // Outbox Tab
        TabSpec statusSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(Status_SPEC);
        statusSpec.setIndicator(Status_SPEC);
        Intent statusIntent = new Intent(this, FragmentStatus.class);
        statusSpec.setContent(statusIntent);

        // Profile Tab
        TabSpec detailsSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(Details_SPEC);
        detailsSpec.setIndicator(Details_SPEC);
        Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(this, FragmentEvents.class);
        detailsSpec.setContent(detailsIntent);


        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(alertsSpec); // Adding Inbox tab
        tabHost.addTab(statusSpec); // Adding Outbox tab
        tabHost.addTab(detailsSpec); // Adding Profile tab


    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * On selecting action bar icons
     * */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Take appropriate action for each action item click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_refresh:
            // refresh
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
            return true;
        case R.id.action_password:
            // help action
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivityAdmin.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
// -------------- EXIT CODE BEGINS ------------------------------

    @Override 
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){ 

        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { //stop your music here
             // To exit application
            onBackPressed2();
        } 
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    }

    public void onBackPressed2() {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
               .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        MainScreen.this.finish();
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", null)
               .show();

    }

}
```

**SOLTUION** :

I added this code to each child :

```
@Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    this.getParent().onBackPressed();   
  }
```

and then called this in my main activity :

```
    @Override 
  public void onBackPressed() {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
               .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       MainScreen.this.finish();
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", null)
               .show();

    }
```

Comment: why onBackPressed2  ?

Comment: i could name it whatever but even with onBackPressed and with @override nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something from this link:

[Key Events in TabActivities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796050/key-events-in-tabactivities)

**Each tab's Activity handled the "back" presses.**

Comment: THANK YOU ,you are a life save =)

Comment: Will there be maybe some Solved mark on my answer? :)

Comment: done =) by the way i found the solution on the link so delete super.onBackPressed();

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was wrong, try this:

```
 /* you don't need this
 @Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){ 

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { //stop your music here
         // To exit application
        onBackPressed();
    } 
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
} */

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
           .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   onBackPressed2();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", null)
           .show();

}

public void onBackPressed2()
{
    MainScreen.this.finish();
}

}
```

Or do the following:

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){ 

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { //stop your music here
         // To exit application
        onBackPressed2();
        return true;
    } 
    else
    {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    }
}
```

Comment: i just tested this , nothing changed

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your question at first. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Thanks , but still nothing happens ,i'm wroking with 4.1.2 platform API 19

Comment: When happens nothing, do you get alert dialog? Or nothing happens when you click yes?

Comment: Tested the second one ,still no ,I DONT UNDERSTAND WHY ITS NOT WORKING , ITS SO LOGIC TRUE

Comment: That is really strange. Look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459848/android-prompt-user-to-save-changes-when-back-button-is-pressed , and also I think maybe you should try intercepting the onKeyUp function as well.

Comment: Apparently not. Well, that's new :)

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);` when you handle the key event.

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){ 

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { //stop your music here
         // To exit application
        onBackPressed2();
        return true; 
    } 
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
}
```

Comment: Deleted that and teste pure OnBackPressed() , still nothing

Answer (score 0):

you need to put onBackPressed() method inside FragmentAlerts.class. MainActivity is extends by TabActivity so default call gets to your first tab. so call your onbacpress indside first activity i.e FragmentAlerts.

Comment: solved by adding OnBackPressed() in each Fragment function for me

Comment: good. TabActivity represent declaration of Tabs only if you want to perform any key events then implement it inside that particular Activity.